# reference to a field outside of the subquery

Tags: sql

I have this table:

[image]

And this other table:

[image]

I left join the second table to the first:

```
select
 planningitems.costtype_id,
 costcentercode_id,
 fv.fix,
 fv.var
from
 planningitems
left join 
(select
  fix,
  var,
  costtype_id,
  costcenter_id
 from fixvar
 where
  costcenter_id=10 or (costcenter_id=-1 and costtype_id not in (select costtype_id from fixvar where costcenter_id=10))
) as fv on fv.costtype_id=planningitems.costtype_id
```

It gives the correct result, but I would like to make the `costcenter_id` variable. I mean, I want to replace `costcenter_id=10` to `costcenter_id=planningitems.costcentercode_id`.

How it is possible?

I use firebird, but I think, this is a common sql issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing this does what you want:

```
select pi.costtype_id, costcentercode_id, fv.fix, fv.var
from planningitems pi left join 
     fixvar fv
     on fv.costtype_id = pi.costtype_id and
        (fv.costcenter_id = pi.costcenter_id or
         fv.costcenter_id = -1 and
         fv.costtype_id not in (select fv2.costtype_id from fixvar fv2 where fv2.costcenter_id = pi.costcenter_id)
        );
```

The logic in your query is very hard to follow.  I'm pretty sure there is an easier way to do what you want.  You might consider asking *another* question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: This is exactly that, what I wanted. Thank you.